# jQuery Validate formatting rules for range limits

Tags: asp.net, jquery-validate

I have a large table of text inputs for which a set of custom attributes are being created on the server side.  These attributes included "min" and "max" which were used with the jQuery Validate plugin.

Due to a change in the requirements (of course), we now have to update the attributes to a range type, however the Validate plugin isn't interpreting the formatting of the range rule correctly (or perhaps it's more accurate to say I'm not formatting the rule correctly) and now I have problems.

The generated output for the input boxes looks like this:

```
<input type="text" producttype="CCC" code="ESTFEE" range="460, 500" class="currency required" id="txtEstFeeCCC" value="460.00" name="txtEstFeeCCC">
```

I've also tried the following:

```
<input type="text" producttype="CCC" code="ESTFEE" range="[460, 500]" class="currency required" id="txtEstFeeCCC" value="460.00" name="txtEstFeeCCC">
```

In either case, the message returned is either:

> Please enter a value between 4 and 6.

or

> Please enter a value between NaN and 4

respectively.  Neither of which has anything to do with the 460 - 500 range in question.

The jQuery code calling the validate function is just the vanilla call:

```
$("#btnSave").click(function() {
    validator.form();
    ... 
    });
```

How should an input attribute for jQuery Validate range be formatted so that the correct number range limit is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
<input type="text" id="field1" name="field1" class="{required: true, range: [460, 500]}">
```

You could, of course, always just store the values as a range but output as `min` and `max` properties still

Comment: I hadn't been using the jQuery meta plugin, but I am now (and should have from the outset) and this has resolved the issue as your answer suggested.

Comment: Sorry, hadn't realised you didn't have the plugin. Glad my answer helped a bit :)